# Why won't my program remove a string from the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My code is a basic file creator and manager. The main way I organise all the files are in a directory text file. I import it into an array so the program can access it. My delete button doesn't remove the string from the ArrayList. How can i fix this?

```
//This part initialises the code and imports the array
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    ArrayList<String> directory = new ArrayList();
    String content1;

    try {
        content1 = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("directory.txt")));

        output.setText(content1);
        directory.add(content1);

        refresh();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(filemanagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

//This allows me to refresh the output text area
private void refresh() {
    String content = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < directory.size(); i++) {
        content = content + directory.get(i) + "\n"; 
    } 
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("directory.txt"), directory);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(filemanagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    output.setText(content);
    System.out.println(directory);
}

//This deletes the file from the directory and the actual file
private void deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    directory.remove(input.getText());
    String fileDelete = input.getText();
    directory.remove(input.getText());
    Path deletefile = (Paths.get(fileDelete + ".txt"));

    try {
        Files.delete(deletefile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(filemanagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("directory.txt"), directory);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(filemanagerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: you did define `ArrayList<String> directory = new ArrayList();` in the scope of the method `startActionPerformed`. As a result only this local `ArrayList`  will hold values, but as these are never populated to the field `directory`, which is defined somewhere there, your dictory will allways work on nothing.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Are you sure you don't have a scope issue?

Comment: The `ArrayList<String> directory = new ArrayList();` comes before the `startActionPreformed`. I copied it to here wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the file open when you debugging it. Make sure the program can access it